# Bad Request When using passport.js with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a chat application using node.js express socket.io and mongodb. I have added authentication feature using passport.js for the register route as shown in the code below. I am getting a bad request errror when I am trying to sign up. It is happening in line 133. I have printed out the request and would be greatly helpful for anyone who would hep me solve it. I have searched google alot and couldn't find the solution. (Check the authenticate function below. My Other files are follows:

**Below is the app.js code**

```js
var express = require("express"),

 
 mongoose = require("mongoose"),

 app     = express(),

 server  = require("http").createServer(app),

 bodyParser = require("body-parser"),

 io = require("socket.io").listen(server),

 //Authentication tools
 passport   = require("passport"),
 LocalStrategy  = require("passport-local"),


 //require all models

 User = require("./models/user");


//Connect a database
var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || "mongodb://localhost/chatApplication";
mongoose.connect(url);


app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//Passport Authentication(Keep at end)

 //creating a session.
app.use(require("express-session")({
 secret:"A socket app",
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: false
}));

//Initialze a session and passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


//Adding a function to all the paths
app.use(function(req,res,next){
 console.log("User: - " + req.user);
 res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
 next();
});



//When The Conection is established and active.
io.sockets.on("connection",function(userSocket){
 console.log("Socket" + userSocket.id);
 userSocket.on("sendMessage",function(data){

  //broadcasting message to users.
  io.sockets.emit("newMessage",data);
 });
});



//Root Routes
app.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.render("index");
});


//Chat Routes
app.get("/chat",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
 res.render("chats/chat");
});


//Authentication Routes

//Login Routes
app.get("/login",function(req,res){
 res.render("authentication/login");
});


app.post("/login",function(req,res){
 console.log("ID: - " + req.params.id);
 res.redirect("/chat");
});


//Register Routes
app.get("/register",function(req,res){
 res.render("authentication/register");
});


app.post("/register",function(req,res){
 //Get New User;
 
 var userName = new User({username:req.body.name});
 
  //Register the new User
 User.register(userName,req.body.password,function(err,user){
  if(err){
   
   console.log(err);
   res.redirect("/register");
  }
  else{
   console.log("User : - "+user);
   console.log(req);
   
   passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
    console.log("User Id " + user._id);
    res.redirect("/chat");

   });
   
  }
 });

});

function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
 if(req.isAuthenticated()){
  return next();
 }
 else{
  res.redirect("/login");
 }
}



var server = app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
 console.log("Connected on server");
});
```

```html
var express = require("express"),
 
 mongoose = require("mongoose"),

 app     = express(),

 server  = require("http").createServer(app),

 bodyParser = require("body-parser"),

 io = require("socket.io").listen(server),

 //Authentication tools
 passport   = require("passport"),
 LocalStrategy  = require("passport-local"),


 //require all models

 User = require("./models/user");



//Connect a database
var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || "mongodb://localhost/chatApplication";
mongoose.connect(url);


app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//Passport Authentication(Keep at end)

 //creating a session.
app.use(require("express-session")({
 secret:"A socket app",
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: false
}));

//Initialze a session and passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());



//Adding a function to all the paths
app.use(function(req,res,next){
 console.log("User: - " + req.user);
 res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
 next();
});






//When The Conection is established and active.
io.sockets.on("connection",function(userSocket){
 console.log("Socket" + userSocket.id);
 userSocket.on("sendMessage",function(data){

  //broadcasting message to users.
  io.sockets.emit("newMessage",data);
 });
});



//Root Routes
app.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.render("index");
});


//Chat Routes
app.get("/chat",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
 res.render("chats/chat");
});


//Authentication Routes

//Login Routes
app.get("/login",function(req,res){
 res.render("authentication/login");
});


app.post("/login",function(req,res){
 console.log("ID: - " + req.params.id);
 res.redirect("/chat");
});


//Register Routes
app.get("/register",function(req,res){
 res.render("authentication/register");
});


app.post("/register",function(req,res){
 //Get New User;
 
 var userName = new User({username:req.body.name});
 
  //Register the new User
 User.register(userName,req.body.password,function(err,user){
  if(err){
   
   console.log(err);
   res.redirect("/register");
  }
  else{
   console.log("User : - "+user);
   console.log(req);
   
   passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
    console.log("User Id " + user._id);
    res.redirect("/chat");

   });
   
  }
 });

});

function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
 if(req.isAuthenticated()){
  return next();
 }
 else{
  res.redirect("/login");
 }
}


var server = app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
 console.log("Connected on server");
});
```

**User.js(Model)**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});



userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

**Register.ejs**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>


<style type="text/css">
    #form{
        margin:0px auto;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width:47%;

    }


    h1{
        text-align: center;
    }


    #container{
        margin-top: 200px;
        width:24em;
    }


</style>



<div class="container bg-light border-light rounded" id="container">

    <form action="/register" id= "form" method="POST">

        <h1 class="py-3"> Sign UP!!</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your username">

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary mx-5" value="Sign Up">

        </div>
    </form>
</div>















<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Comment: It looks like you pasted the same thing twice, I dont see the actual error message or the request, just 2 copies of the same code.

Comment: On the line passport.authenticate in the register post route i get an error of bad request in browser.

Comment: I accidentally posted it twice.I don't know the reason for the error.